# Why javascript stops working when using codekit and foundation zurb?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm new to coding and working with JS.

I've installed Codekit and have built a new Foundation 6 project.

This all runs fine.

However it builds a "node modules" folder inside the "build" folder, then calls on the script in the index.html like this...

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/what-input/dist/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js"></script>
```

How do I build all of this .js into one file? As I've read that you only really need to make one request to make the .js work.

When I prepend these scripts to a new app.js file, the javascript seems to stop working.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Hi Lain, are you seeing any error in the output console ?

Comment: No errors in the console. The javascript just seems to stop working in elements like "Reveal"

Comment: @lain Waugh it would help us if you can edit your question and add that output in the description